# Searching replacement for broken plug

Tags: plug

[image]Could someone tell me the specification of this plug?
The plug is from the camera and microphone unit of my laptop lenovo u330 touch. I damaged it and want to replace it. i hope to find a replacement including wires, with i could link to the wires of the old cable after cutting off the old plug.

thank you for your quick replies so far!
I added a new picture of the back, and i measured the distance: 4 mm between 5 contacts, leeding to a distance of 0.8 mm between the contacts.
still hoping to find an solution

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post some more pictures from other angles?  Also, how big is it (in mm)?

Comment: the back of the plug looks like a variety of plugs, therefore it cannot be identified ... the plug probably would not come with wires ... you would have to push the existing wires into the plug by using a crimp tool

Comment: Those look like punch-down terminations, but smaller than the typical 2.54mm pitch.  Are you able to measure the pitch (from the middle of the black wire to the middle of the white wire divided by 7 will be more accurate than trying to measure just one).

Comment: Looks like 0.8 mm pitch. So it is a 0.8 mm insulation displacement connector. If you type "0.8mm IDC connector" in a search engine you may get somewhere. I found one possible candidate, the JST SUR series of connectors. But I am not sure if it is a match. https://www.jst.com/products/insulation-displacement-connectors-wire-to-board-type/sur-connector/

Comment: Tank You! I am going with the JST SUR 0,8 mm pitch 8 pin and will try to find one. Thanks so far!

Comment: @Flo Farnell (UK) sells a [15cm cable with 8-position JST 0.8mm plugs](https://de.farnell.com/de-DE/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/08sur-08sur-32w150/lead-8way-0-8mm-150mm/dp/3849673?st=0.8mm%20connector).  It's €12,53 delivered to DE.  I'm not positive it's the same connector though.  [Here's the datasheet.](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/105075.pdf)  You could cut the old connector off, cut the new cable in half, and solder the wires together.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look on [Mouser](https://mouser.com) and [Digikey](https://digikey.com) but I didn't see anything that looks remotely like that connector.  Farnell (UK) sells [a cable](https://de.farnell.com/de-DE/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/08sur-08sur-32w150/lead-8way-0-8mm-150mm/dp/3849673?st=0.8mm%20connector) (€13,53 delivered to DE) that *might* have the same connector.  I'm not sure the connector is the same though ([here's the datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/105075.pdf)).

Honestly, your best option IMO is to get a (used) replacement for either the cable or the cable and board from ebay<sup>1</sup>.  Cable with the webcam board: [US$10](https://www.ebay.com/itm/333911344936?hash=item4dbeaac728:g:3%7EYAAOSwqNBgQsCb).  Or just the cable: [CA$39](https://www.ebay.com/itm/303625558187?hash=item46b17e58ab:g:dU0AAOSwTeNfBgrh) or [US$17](https://www.ebay.com/itm/252846173822?hash=item3adece6e7e:g:aXAAAOSw0c9bmBR-).  Going the ebay route is probably cheaper too since you're looking at probably US$5-US$8 minimum for shipping from a distributer like Mouser.

<sup>1</sup>All prices above include shipping.  I am in no way affiliated with any of the sellers I linked to.

Comment: Thank you! I am in germany and didnt find any offer on ebay here, but the cable name is a great idea!

Comment: @Flo The US$17 cable offers shipping to DE for US$17 (US$34 total).  If you go the ebay route be sure to check the item photos to make sure the cable is the same as the one you are replacing.